# classNotFoundException when running two ignite servers

Tags: ignite

when I am trying to run two ignite servers I am getting the following errors.
1)    Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling.
2)    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rg.netlink.app.config.ServerConfigurationFactory$2

even after peerClassLoadingENabled on both servers this error keeps persisting.

please help.

How can I run two ignite servers. Did anybody successfully run two ignite servers.

Answer (score 1):

Can you figure out what's `ServerConfigurationFactory$2`?

I would imagine that for some reason your Ignite node contains some class in its configuration which is absent on other nodes. Nodes pass their configuration on discovery so this will cause problems. Make sure that you only use stock Ignite configuration classes and do not override them with custom implementations/wrappers.

Comment: dont worry about it it is a class in my project which contains CacheConfigurations.

Comment: No class is overridden. And can you give me some ignite server code that has run successfully.

Comment: You can just run several bin/ignite.sh from binary distro. `$2` in the class name means that it is an anonymous subclass and you do override something.

Comment: Alamar thanks but Actually i am running two different java applications.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding by request service.

Comment: Well alam that code runs many servers in single jvm . But i want to run them in two different jvms. Plzzz suggest

Comment: I can only help you if you actually respond to my suggestions. I had a few upstream.